Thriller where teens break into a house while the homeowner is away
I saw a trailer not too long for a film, could be a newer film or could be a film from a years ago (maybe 2013). 
The trailer was about these teenagers that invade the home of a rich family and/or neighbor while the family is away. And they live in the house for the weekend. One of the teenagers makes love to a girl in the rich family's master bedroom. But the family that owns the house returns early. 
At one point in the trailer, the home owner (seems like a father) is disappointed in the kitchen, with an angry look on his face because of the situation. The couple that invaded the home quickly but quietly escapes out a side door in the background. They avoid being seen as they leave. That's all I can remember. Seemed very suspenseful. The man who owns the house seems hell bent on finding out who broke in and used his home while he was away. The actor who plays the home owner is someone in the B-range. Kind of like Sam Neill or Bruce Greenwood but it's neither of them. 
This movie seemed really interesting and I'm stuck. Been searching for it for months. Can't remember where I saw the trailer. Any ideas? I believe it was a more independent film. Don't think it received a theatrical release though I could be wrong as it can be a "coming soon" film as well. 
Can anyone identify this thriller?

Sounds like Squatters from 2014.

Home early from their vacation, a wealthy Pacific Palisades family discovers a pair of homeless young drifters who were squatting in their home.

The father is Richard Dreyfuss. You can see the trailer here, where they sneak out while the dad surveys the apartment angrily near the end:



